# SQL order by datetime when using group by

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am using an SQL Query to group by a field

```
SELECT * from text_messages group by number order by datetime DESC
```

which works fine, however its not showing the latest column for each `group by`

for example, i have 2 rows with the same number and the following datetime:

```
2015-11-01 10:43:39
2015-10-31 22:50:17
```

so its only showing one of these which is the `2015-10-31 22:50:17`

how can i make it show the latest column and not the earlies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MAX` aggregate function:

```
SELECT `number`, MAX(`datetime`)  AS `datetime`
FROM text_messages 
GROUP BY `number`
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC;
```

Also note that `datetime` is keyword and it should be renamed or you need to quote it with backticks.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a13e9/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: While datetime is a keyword it`s not a reserved word

Comment: @Mihai Good practise says don't use keyword/reserved word/future words for identifiers